# C++ File input and output:cannot input

Tags: c++, io

The following C++ code is to read a txt file and then write the numbers of chars in each line and the number of all chars in the txt file.I use MS Visual Studio 2008.But something is wrong.Only the number of all chars is input into the txt files,**but the numbers of each line are not input into the txt files**.Now I cannot figure it out.Could someone give me some advice?Thanks a lot!

And my another question is what should I do to ***insert something in the middle of the txt file?***

This is my Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream inOut("copy.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

if (!inOut)
{
    cerr << "ERROR:cannot open file!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

int cnt = 0;
char ch;

inOut.seekg(0);

while(inOut.get(ch))
{
    cout.put(ch);
    ++cnt;
    if ('\n' == ch)
    {
        ios::pos_type mark = inOut.tellg();

        if (!inOut)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        inOut << cnt;
        inOut.put(' ');

        inOut.seekg(mark);
    }
}
inOut.clear();
inOut << cnt << endl;
cout << "[" << cnt << "]" << endl;
}
```

The txt file before running:
[image]

The txt file after running:
[image]

The result in command line:
[image]

Comment: Does the spaces also count as chars?

Comment: Yes~I count the spaces as chars.

Comment: Perhaps your line endings are not newline characters \n but instead return characters \r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream inOut("copy.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

if (!inOut)
{
    cerr << "ERROR:cannot open file!" << endl;
    return -1;
}

int cnt = 0;
int cntline=0;
char ch;

inOut.seekg(0);

while(inOut.get(ch))
{
    cout.put(ch);
    //++cnt         it include '\n' it  should put behind of "if"
    if ('\n' == ch)
    {   ios::pos_type mark = inOut.tellg();

        if (!inOut)
        {
            cerr << "ERROR!" << endl;
            return -1;
        }
        cntline=cnt-cntline;        //add it to account the number of chars of each line
        inOut.seekg(0,ios::end);   //here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!  add this , the resault is finally right!  the reason it's down here.
        inOut << cntline;
        cntline=cnt;                // and here! it can assure the number of the chars of each line be right!
        inOut.put(' ');
        inOut.seekg(mark);
    }
    else
    {
        ++cnt;  //   it's here!
    }
}
inOut.clear();
inOut << cnt << endl;
cout << "[" << cnt << "]" << endl;
}
```

**inOut.seekg(0,ios::end)**
i'am not sure it,but you can take it a reference.

you open file with "ios::app",so the VS 2008 only allows you to add text **start from the end of file** (it won't happened in vc 6.0).

if the file is :

1. it's compile by
2. vs 2008

when get the first '\n' the file pointer is pointing to'vs 2008'(yes,it just like the common pointer point the string ). and i debug it then find a value of the stream object named _Wrotesome .its value is false! 
so i think the compiler think the file pointer point at o const sting.so you just can't write anything whis this position. so i add the code  **inOut.seekg(0,ios::end);**.now you
can write anything you want to this text!

wish this can help you !

Comment: What compiler do you use?I use MS Visual Studio 2008,but I cannot get your result~~

Comment: i use vc6.0 and i tried using MS Visual Studio 2008 then have the same problem as yours.and i'known why . i'll edit my answer again.please see it!

Comment: Yes,I can solve the problem by this way.But what should I do if I want to insert something in the middle of the txt file?Do you know how to do that?

Comment: Oh!you can't insert something in the middle of the txt file without rewriting the date behide it.if you want,you can copy the file date into a buffer or fractionally copy and rewrite the date into annew file ,then delete the old file.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know fstream's very well, but I think you want to change the way you are doing this.  You can think of a file as a contiguous piece of memory.  Appending on the end is easy, but inserting in the middle can be problematic.  In particular, if you do insert something, then your `seekg` might not be valid.

I would recommend three strategies:

1. Understand what is going on currently (try closing file before `seekg` and see if anything gets written by the `inOut << cnt;`)
2. Read from one file, write to a different file -- this will most likely be more efficient and less complicated than trying to modify the file in place.
3. Read from source file, store and modify in memory, write out modified buffer to original file.  For large files, this might be less efficient than #2, but it means you don't need two files on disk.

Comment: I add the the  code inOut.seekg(ios::end); before inOut << cnt;inOut.put(' '); in the while loop.And I can input the numbers of chars in each line to the end of the txt file.I think the problem is I want to insert them in the middle,as you have said.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you choose std::fstream as your tool. If std::fstream is not asked or necessary,  I would like to provide a example to solve your problem. Here's some limitation:

a. I read all the file into memory in one ReadFile operation. If your file is large, you may replace it with a loop.
b. I suppose your line separator is '\n'.
c. I add [line_count] before the '\n', which look like better.

here's my code.

```
#include "windows.h"
#include "sstream"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HANDLE hFile = ::CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\wujian\\Desktop\\pingback - Copy.log", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    DWORD dwSize = ::GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
    if (dwSize)
    {
        char *pBuffer = new char[dwSize];
        DWORD dwRead = 0;
        ::ReadFile(hFile, pBuffer, dwSize, &dwRead, NULL);
        if (dwRead == dwSize)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
                    int iPos = 0;
            int iLine = 0;
            while (iPos < dwSize)
            {
                if (pBuffer[iPos] == '\n')
                {
                    ss << '[' << iLine << ']';
                    iLine = 0;
                }
                ss << pBuffer[iPos];
                iPos ++, iLine ++;
            }
            ss << '[' << dwSize << ']';
            ::SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);
            DWORD dwWrite = 0;
            ::WriteFile(hFile, ss.str().c_str(), ss.str().length(), &dwWrite, NULL;
            }
            ::CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```